# Child style overriden by parent style CSS (different issues)

Tags: html, css, html-table

Sorry.. I'm just a little bit confused with other answer in SO..

I have 2 tables, 
and one of them rendered inside a table. (table in table)

```
<table class="master">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>
       <table class="detail">
         <tr>
             <td>ID</td><td>Order</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>1</td><td>CA09-WYOMING-BR</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

style

```
<style>
    table.detail{
        border:1px solid red;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        /* etc...about 20 lines code */
    }
    table.detail td{
        border:1px solid red; 
        background:red;
        /* etc...about 20 lines code */
    }
    table.master {
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.master td {
        border:1px solid black;
        background:gray;
    }
</style>
```

And the detail table style not rendered properly because overridden by parent table CSS.
I know there are **!important** tag to make child CSS style not overridden, but if the CSS style about 20 lines of code should I add '!important' tag to all of them?

?

http://jsfiddle.net/vxdM3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `!important` here...  Reverse the order of your styles. Put the css for the `master` table before `detail`.  The way you have it is that the css for `detail` is being applied first then the `master` css is applied overriding what was set for `detailed`.

[re-orded css fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxdM3/2/)

Or if you don't want to move css around you can update the selectors to `table.master table.detail{}` and `table.master table.detail td{}`.

[updated selector fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxdM3/3/)

Comment: Just to expand on this answer a little: this is because CSS is applied from top to bottom, and apply to all decendents of an element. The styles applied to `table.master td` affect all `td` elements under `table.master` (its decendants). If you only want to change direct children, you should look in to the `>` child combinator selector.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, I use > to avoid styling nested elements unintentionally.

```
.master > tr > td
{
    ....
}
```

Actually, since I always use tbody, it is more like:

```
.master > tbody > tr > td
```

I don't like surprises, so I try to be careful to write css that is very explicit on what it is styling.  Sure, it is a bit slower, but I find it is insignificant to the user experience and I can get stuff done a lot quicker.  Others may do it differently, of course.